Why does TypeScript allow assigning a more narrow function to a function type which is broader?
I just had some code crash in production because I had defined an interface containing a few functions, where some parameters were union types, and one of the implementations of this interface explicitly declared the function parameters as only one of the types of the union specified in the interface's function type.
Consider this code:
interface Api {
  foo(x: string | number, y?: string): boolean;
}

const x: Api = {
  foo(x: string, y: string) {
    // Hey I just narrowed the function parameter types - why was this OK? 
  
    // crashes if y is undefined
    return y.length > 0;
  }
}

x.foo(42);

Playground
Why does this code compile (and instead crash in runtime due to calling the function with a number, which is OK according to the interface)?

Your example has two changes - narrowing of x from string | number to string and narrowing of y from (~) string | undefined to string. Would e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAdjIN4ChnIwD2RAFAB4BcyAzmFKAObIA+yIArgLYBG0AlNR4kANhDggA3LgC+uXAiIg6yKmkzIAvDnyESFanQYhG-HQQIB6S8gASEAJ7IAksgBWHFSDhQoRAO4QACbIYAAWKDAcIAhgwErI6D5wXBCQUKEO6BA0yAC0yP5hTv5wueHAuQDyANIA-MjyFshQaRxQIKoAdGIm4cgAfMgADNIEcnK45F3EZAAsAEz80kA suffice?

That does not address the problem. My question is WHY TypeScript allows the function implementation to be narrower than the function type, not how I can get around it by changing my example code to just one change. I was just trying to illustrate the issue more clearly by showing that the code compiles even with an implementation that does not handle all possible types of the function type in the interface.

Or did you mean "does this suffice as a MRE"? If so, yes I guess the slightly simpler example still illustrates the point, and it is indeed more minimal, if it matters. However, your example doesn't actually crash since length accessed on a number is simply undefined, not an invalid property access like in my example, so I think your example is slightly less illustrative.
Anyway, I think my example is easy enough for us to discuss the problem instead of how to best formulate the smallest possible MRE. ‍♂️

I'm not saying that gets around it (it still has an issue because a number doesn't have a .length), I'm saying I think it illustrates the same problem with less code. I don't think "more minimal" is a thing, if there's a simpler example then the other one is by definition just not minimal - if you can give an example with one parameter rather than two, nobody has to wonder which parameter you're asking about.

Also: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#behavior-that-looks-wrong-and-arguably-is-but-is-currently-working-as-intended

The bivariance part, and that methods are excluded, was interesting, thanks. That does explain it, albeit in a very unsatisfactory way. :)

Is it really "very unsatisfactory"? You can change your method syntax to function expression syntax as shown here and get the enforcement you want.
